# Function override

Tags: function, go

I found something interesting in Go. Let's say I have my package name is `mypkg`, inside `mypkg`, I have two functions:

```
package mypkg
func MyFunc0(){
    //...
}
var MyFunc1 = func(){
    //...
}
```

Now in my `main` package, it is possible to override `MyFunc1`, like this:

```
mypkg.MyFunc1 = func(){
   // new logic
}
```

However, it is not possible to override `MyFunc0` the same way. So now a question is raised. What are the differences between the two ways of declaring a function? Is this behavior difference intended?

Comment: You aren't overriding anything. `MyFunc1` is a *variable* and you're simply changing it. That's what variables do, they vary. Otherwise they'd be constants. (The fact that a variable can hold a function and you can use that variable to call the function without any special syntax is irrelevant; it's just syntactical difference from C function pointers for example.)

Comment: I'm actually using it as the abstract method in Java. I'm providing the basic behavior, and am expecting the client to override the default behavior with their more specific behaviors if they like. Because I want the library to be abstract and to know nothing about the implementation details. Forgive my words, I came from Java, and my brain is deeply affected that way. Is it wrong to use it this way?

Comment: This can be more easily achieved using interfaces (very similar to Java)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`MyFunc0` is a function declaration (https://golang.org/ref/spec#Function_declarations)

`MyFunc1` is not a function declaration. It is a variable (https://golang.org/ref/spec#Variable_declarations) of type func (see https://golang.org/ref/spec#Function_types, https://golang.org/ref/spec#Function_literals). It has an initial value, but can be changed to hold a different value/function (as long as function signatures match).

Comment: So effectively, is there any significant difference between these two ways of writing a function, other than the possibility of being overridden?

Comment: Unless there is a good reason not to you should always use function declaration (like `MyFunc0`). It is easier to read and it cannot change in a surprising way. To be honest I am not sure if there are any differences. I guess linker won't be able to remove function in a var from the resulting exe file even if it is not used.

Comment: Why? Is function override evil?

Comment: Thanks @kostya. Still want to know if one is more effective, or consumes less memory than the other?

Comment: A static function can be optimized in ways that a mutable function literal (i.e. a variable that holds a function) cannot. For example, it is possible to inline static functions. While Go absolutely supports function literals, it is preferred to only use them when there is a particular goal in mind. It isn't "overriding" any more than `x = 1` is "overriding" `x`. It's assignment in Go. (In other languages, like ML, it *is* overriding, but `x = 1` is *also* overriding in ML.)

Answer (score 0):

I learning go language (and English :P), and in the tour of go is a exersie: Fibonacci closure

(https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/22)

The result is:
0
1
1
2
3
5
8
13
21
34

The main function is:

```
func main() {
    f := fibonacci()
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        fmt.Println(f())
    }
}
```

And my first solution was:

```
func fibonacci() func() int {
    antant := 0
    ant := 1
    i := 0
    return func() int {
        var result int
        if i == 0 || i == 1 {
            result = i
            i++
            return result
        }
        result = antant + ant
        antant = ant
        ant = result
        return result
    }
}
```

But I didn't want ask in heach call to f() if was the firsth or second call (`if i == 0 || i == 1`). The result was a function auto-override:

```
type doFibonacci func(*doFibonacci) int

func fibonacci() func() int {
    antant := 0
    ant := 1
    i := 0
    doFibo := doFibonacci(func(ptrDo *doFibonacci) int {
        var result int
        if i == 0 || i == 1 {
            result = i
            i++
            return result
        }
        *ptrDo = func(ptrDo *doFibonacci) int {
            var result int
            result = antant + ant
            antant = ant
            ant = result
            return result
        }
        return (*ptrDo)(ptrDo)
    })
    return func() int {
        return doFibo(&doFibo)
    }
}
```

I apologize for my English.

Comment: I think `doFibonacci ` is a type alias.